# What is the recommended HTTP POST content length?

Tags: http, rest, http-post, load-balancing

I have several clients that constantly post data to a REST service. REST service is put behind a network load balancer. Each client sends 100 - 500 MB a day and I need to support 500+ clients.

I can POST either very large packets, this will reduce overhead for TCP/IP session set up and HTTP headers. This will, however, firmly tie one client to a particular server and limit my scalability options. Alternatively, I can send small HTTP packets, which I can load balance well, but I will get more overhead for TCP/IP session set up and HTTP headers.

**What is the recommended packet size for HTTP POST? Or how can I calculate one for my environment?**

Answer (score 2):

There is no recommended size.

While HTTP POST size is not constrained by the RFCs, since HTTP is a commodity protocol implementing request / response type messaging, most of the infrastructure is configured around the idea that TCP connections are not particularly long lasting / does not carry significant amounts of data. i.e. there will be factors outside your control which may impact the service - although HTTP supports range requests for responses, there is no corollary for requests.

You can get around a lot of these (although not all) by using HTTPS. However you still need to think about how you detect/manage outages - are you happy to wait for a TCP timeout?

With 500+ clients presumably using the system quite heavily, the congestion avoidance limits shouldn't be a problem - whether TCP window scaling is likely to be an issue depends on how the system is used. HTTP handshakes should not be an issue unless you restrict the request size to something silly.

If the service is highly dependant on clients pushing lots of data on to your server, then I'd encourage you to look at parsing the data on the client (given the volume, presumably it's coming from files - implying a signed java applet or javascript with UniversalBrowserRead privilege) then sending it over a bi-directional communication channel (e.g. websocket).

Leaving that aside for now, the only way you can find out what the route between your clients and your server will support is to measure it - and monitor it. I would expect that a 2Mb upload size would work pretty much anywhere, while a 10Mb size would work most of the time within the US or Europe - and that you could probably increase this to 50Mb as long as there's no mobile clients.

But if you want to maintain the effectiveness of the service you'll need to monitor bandwidth, packet loss and lost connections.